# Intercept method declaration

Tags: java, osgi, aspectj

I have the following method:

```
@OnEvent
public void onEvent(Event event) {
}
```

Now, I am puzzled whether AspectJ can intercept the method "declaration", i.e. neither its call nor its execution, in order to provide functionality somewhere else.
The objective is to "take" that method and register it as a handler of events into the OSGi service registry:

```
    public void start(BundleContext bc) {
    bc.registerService(EventHandler.class, new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            // TODO get a "reference" of the onEvent(...) method and call it here
            onEventJoinPoint.proceed(event);
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is conceptually impossible in AspectJ and probably also in any other AOP framework. But you have several alternatives:

- How about putting marker annotations in all places where the aspect should kick in? There you could parametrise the annotation so as to mention which method to call.
- Or if you really want to have it all in one place and avoid config files, use a configuration class similar to Spring. The class or one of its methods which you call when booting up your component, would carry all config annotations which would thus be interceptable by AspectJ.
- You could also keep the annotation where it is and call the annotated method once after loading the class, intercept the method execution and take note of the method from an aspect, then re-use this information later.

There are other, similar options. But in each case, please note that

- class loading / initialisation order is important,
- if you just have a method and class name, you will need reflection in order to call it, unless the method is either static or the class is a singleton and the method does not rely on any object state, i.e. an instance can easily be obtained and the method be called as often as needed. Then you could maybe even tweak the solution into calling `proceed()` multiple times.

If you have follow-up questions which are too complex for simple comments, please update the main question and notify me. I cannot be any more concrete now because I do not know enough about your use case. Thus, I am not providing any sample code (yet).

Comment: I think I will try to build a custom weaving hook for my OSGi environment.